# startActivity(Context, Class) function not working properly

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having this issue while starting an activity through intents.The issue is that if I go into my XML, and sets AugmentedReality as the main Activity (and the one to be launched as the first), there basically are no problems.

```
<activity android:name=".AugmentedReality" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The application will draw a cube on the camera preview, but then I won't "visit" my other activities "Location", "DescriptionText" and "Description". If I keep the Location activity as the main activity in my XML file, and then press the button that takes me to AugmentedReality activity, I can't see the cube, which is drawn (I have used `Log.v(TAG, "Cube drawn");`, and got spammed).

I am using this code to declare and send the intent from my Location class 
`public class Language extends Activity implements OnClickListener`:

```
    `if (dButton.isPressed()) {
        description = dbh.getDescription("Danish");
        list = dbh.getGPS("Maribo");
        f = new float[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            f[i] = list.get(i);
        }
            intent = new Intent(this, Description.class);
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            }
    }`
```

When I press the dButton, I am sent to my AugmentedReality activity, which only is showing the camera preview. and not the cube. Here's the onCreate method in AugmentedReality

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        camview = new CameraView(this);
        graphics = new GraphicsView(this);
        final Window win = getWindow();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(graphics);
        addContentView(camview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        Log.v("AR", "Content sat");
    }
```

the onSurfaceChanged in GraphicsView:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // GLU.gluLookAt(gl, coords[0], coords[1], 0, 0, 0, 0,
    // orientation[0],
    // orientation[1], orientation[2]);
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(45, 45, 0, 15);
    cube.draw(gl);
```

and of course the draw method inside my Cube Class:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

I hope that somebody can tell me why the cube is only visible when I set AugmentedReality as main in my XML file. The camera has got all the required permissions inside the XML file, and the Location class has got permission to use GPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions about solutions.

I have solved the issue by changing from

```
setContentView(graphics);
addContentView(camView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

into

```
setContentView(camview);
addContentView(graphics, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

camView is an object of my Camera instance, and graphics is an object of my OpenGLES 1.0. Here's the weird thing though: I have tired several time exchanging camView with graphics and counterwise. but anyways: it's working now

Answer (score 0):

Have you mapped Description class in Manifest file? Even you mapped you need to give the permission

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

 <activity android:name=".Description"/>
```

Comment: This is inside my XML file too:                             <activity
            android:name="Description"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>

Comment: Please give the Camera permission  in manifest file, see above code